# Asp.net MVC3 validation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, validation

I have asp.net MVC3 app where validations are done by adding validation attribute in model. 
e.g.

`[Required(ErrorMessage = "Required field")]
        [Display(Name = "SurveyName")]
        [DataType(DataType.Text)]
        public string  SurveyName {get;set;}`

Then I create text box in view

`@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.SurveyQuestions[i].SurveyName)`

and add validation message

```
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SurveyQuestions[i].SurveyName)
```

Scenario here is I create 5 textbox with for loop with same model property Surveyname and I want to validate only first textbox and no validations for rest of the textbox.

Is this possible?

**Edit:**

I used below code for rest of the textboxes but it validation occurs on these fields also.

```
@Html.TextBox("SurveyQuestions[" + i + "].Question", @Model.SurveyQuestions[i].Question)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So finally I got the solutions, though I think it's not the correct way. But it solved my issue.
Steps I did to fix the issue -

1. I observed Html for input fields for which there is an validation error. The input field will have additional attributes such as "data-val-required" and "data-val"
2. Then I added these fields to textbox which needs to be validated.
3. Then I added Html.Validation() for textbox with validation message.

My final code looks like

```
             @if (i == 0)
                {
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.SurveyQuestions[i].Question, new Dictionary<string, object> { { "data-val-required", "required" }, { "data-val", "true" },  { "title", "Question " + (i + 1) }, {"class","QuestionTextBox"} })           
                    <br />
                    @Html.ValidationMessage("SurveyQuestions[0].Question", "At least one question is required.")
                }
                else
                { 
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.SurveyQuestions[i].Question, new { @class = "QuestionTextBox", @title = "Question " + (i + 1) })    
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to create the first one with the following code as you did :

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.SurveyQuestions[i].SurveyName)
```

Then, use `@Html.TextBox` for the rest of it. You just need to hardcode the id and name attributes for your model property.

Comment: I tried this solution but it didn't work. Please see edit section for code changes I did.