# How can I prevent a validation attribute from being generated?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, jquery-validate, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a `DateTime` property in my model, but I'm only interested in the time part:

```
public class MyModel
{
    [Required, DataType.Time]
    public DateTime Time
}
```

In my view, I output it like so:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Time)
```

This used to generate the following html in MVC 3:

```
<input class="text-box single-line" data-val="true" 
    data-val-required="The Time field is required." 
    id="Time" name="Time" type="time" value="" />
```

Now I'm trying this with MVC 4, and this is the html generated:

```
<input class="text-box single-line" data-val="true" 
    data-val-date="The field Time must be a date." 
    data-val-required="The Time field is required." 
    id="Time" name="Time" type="time" value="" />
```

There is an extra attribute `data-val-date` added, which results in a client side validation error, because a time (e.g. "10:30") isn't formated as a date.

I suppose this is a bug in MVC 4 ([I reported it](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/705643/a-data-val-date-attribute-is-generated-for-time-fields-in-asp-net-mvc-4))? But until it's resolved, is there any way to prevent this attribute from being generated? Or even better, is there a way to let it be generated as a `data-val-time` in stead, so I can provide my own client side validation method for time fields?

Answer (score 4):

Not ideal but it will do the job; use JavaScript in your master template to remove the validation:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input[data-val-date]").removeAttr("data-val-date");
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `[DataType("Time")]` instead of `[DataType(DataType.DateTime)]`. This will make MVC not treat your variable as `DateTime`, and then it will not generate the `data-val-date` attribute.

Essentially `[DataType("Time")]` makes your variable a custom type. However, you cannot use any other string name for the custom type. MVC tries to detect the underlying type for a custom type. Only when you name your custom type as `Time`, it will give up the detection.

Answer (score 2):

I can say better option will be to write your own client side validation function. Otherwise you can do some spoofing which I wont say it is right way but it can solve your issue. I had similar issue with respect to MVC validation where I wanted to change the behavior of client side validation. Please see the link

[Asp.net MVC3 validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7618736/asp-net-mvc3-validation/7738725#7738725)

The idea here is you manually add attributes such as "data-val-required" and "data-val" to your input field and then add validation message for it.

Hope it helps you in some way.

**Edit:**

try this

Remove required field attr from model

```
public class MyModel
{    
    public DateTime Time
}
```

Then add attributes to your control as shown below

```
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Time, new Dictionary<string, object> { { "data-val-required", "required" }, { "data-val", "true" }})
    @Html.ValidationMessage("Time", "The Time field is required.")
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this doesn't really solve my problem... I want a specific attribute (`data-val-date`) to *not* be inserted, as it gets inserted automatically somewhere in the MVC pipeline.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried setting the value of the input field as a javascript date object, which in turn passed the validation of the unobtrusive validation.

```
$("#date-input-field").val(new Date(1,0,1970));
$.validator.unobtrusive.parse('#form');
var form = $('#form');
form.validate();
```

This is done with jQuery 1.7.2, validation.unobtrusive and mvc4.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to set `ClientValidationEnabled` and `UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled` to false in the [HtmlHelper](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.htmlhelper(v=vs.118).aspx) class.

```
HtmlHelper.ClientValidationEnabled = false;
HtmlHelper.UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled = false;
```

Comment: I have those in my config. Setting them off did work too.

Comment: But I rather prefer to just set in the View.